# I want to log hours studied every day on desktop, how do I do it?

Tags: time-management

Here's the system that I want:

I choose a subject called "political science". I study it using pomodoro timer for 45 minutes. Then I choose subject called "human sciences" and I use pomodoro for it for 45 minutes. I do this everyday, and I want to log how many hours I am studying these stuffs. How do I do it? Any software's available?

free/paid both ok.

[image]

I've tried ticktick, jira, superproductivity, pomatez, pomotroid but they don't satisfy me. Most of them don't have a concept of states and tags for each pomodoro session.

Comment: What research did you do, and what options did you find that were not satisfactory, and how were they not satisfactory? Often, a google search - in this case, perhaps for "pomodoro with logging" - will give you some good starting points for your research, which will allow anyone who chooses to respond to this question some idea of what _not_ to suggest.

Comment: @barnyad9, does it need to be free?

Comment: @Pacerier No. Paid is good generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [ManicTime](https://www.manictime.com). While its main focus is automatic time tracking based on which program you're currently using, it also has a pomodoro timer and tagging for each session. It has a free version, but the pomodoro timer is only available in the paid version (which has a 30 day trial).

Comment: That's good but is there an app for web/desktop like milki pomodoro for android?

Comment: Ok I just bought milki pomodoro pro.

Comment: @barnyard9 if what you found worked for you and fits your question, then please post it as an answer and accept that so the question is resolved